# Python while _ValueError

Tags: python

In this program if user enter a str input, the program won't run and user will get an error.
how can I develope my program to tell the user that input is wrong?
Could you help me with this problem please?

```
summation = 0
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter your input \n")
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    else:
        summation = summation + float(user_input)
        print("End \n", "SUMMATION = ", summation)

"conention.py/while.py"
Enter your input 
Hi
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\python\name conention.py\while.py", line 7, 
in <module> summation = summation + float(user_input)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Hi'

PS C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\python>
```

Comment: As the error said, you typed a string instead an integer or a float as input. What are you interested in?

Comment: you run `float("Hi")` and this makes problem. You should use `try/except` to catch error and do something or skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You run `float("Hi")` and this makes problem.

You should use `try/except` to catch error and do something or skip it.

For example.

```
summation = 0

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter your input \n")
    
    if user_input.lower() == "done":
        break
    
    try:
        summation = summation + float(user_input)
        print("End \n", "SUMMATION = ", summation)
    except ValueError:
        print('It is not float value:', user_input)
```